# Операционная система

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Предложение такое: "Друг пришел к нему, чтобы установить операционную систему "Виндоус". Честно говоря, я никак не могу сообразить, как правильно писать название системы. Оно настолько на слуху, что кавычки и большая буква уже смотрятся как-то не совсем уместно. И как вообще корректнее писать в данном случае: английскими буквами или русскими? И, если английскими, то надо ли брать в кавычки (в английском ведь совсем другие пунктуационные правила)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если такие названия пишутся кириллицей, то в кавычках, если латиницей, то в русском тексте - без кавычек. В обоих случаях - с большой буквы. Переводить ли в кириллицу, обычно решают в зависимости от того, создаёт ли проблемы чтение латинского названия, можно ли по русской транскрипции его однозначно отнести к тому, о чём говорится и т.п. В данном случае я оставил бы в латинице: не прижилась в текстах транслитерация всем понятного слова и никто по-русски не произносит его как "виндофс" (говорят: "виндоус", просто приглушая "з"). А странноватое "Виндовс" возникло в технических форумах - от стремления ускорить набор слова на "клаве".

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, по английски надо писать. И без кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза "Эта блондинка вызвала мальчика из магазина, тот ей убил вполне живого линуха, поставил седьмого мастдая, а потом и говорит - лицензию покупай, а то экран почернеет" вряд ли будет понятна за пределами компьютерных форумов...

А с запятой - на вкус. Можно написать "Я купил автомобиль "Феррари"", а можно - "Я купил автомобиль, "Феррари"". Правда, "операционная система Windows", скорее, единый термин.

Comment: >тот ей убил вполне живого линуха, поставил седьмого мастдая

Линукс форева! Винда - ацтой :-)

Answer (score 1):

По-русски название операционной системы будет "Виндовс". Что касается знаков препинания, то можно обойтись без кавычек, но тогда необходимо поставить запятую, так в этом случае "Виндовс" будет уточнением какая именно операционная система. Я считаю, что строчная буква в этом слове возможна при передаче разговорного стиля, где "виндовс" может обозначать операционную систему вообще, но так как из контекста предложения вытекает, что автор различет эти понятия я бы рекомендовал заглавную букву и кавычки:

> Друг пришел к нему установить операционную систему "Виндовс".

Answer (score 1):

Писать можно по-разному... Профи говорят:  Винды, на крайний случай, по-старому: окошки поставить, проапгрейдить. В  литературе это ОС "MS Windows", подразумевается фирма изготовитель  "Microsoft", ради бога, не искажайте название продукта и торговой марки производителя... На западе это не принято. Дурной тон.  Как пишется, так и читается -- виндоуз, но это русский сленг, не допускается  в технической и специальной переписке, и  в  литературе.

В личных письмах -- да как угодно, если вас понимает адресат. Но лучше придерживаться общепринятого стандарта. Дисциплинирует.

Comment: Профи говорят не "винды", а "винда"))

Comment: отстой, ацтой, молодежь, ату вас, ни бельмеса в английском. множественное число.

Comment: @fatyalink, На форуме  "Русский язык" не стоит использовать жаргонную, ненормативную и эмоционально окрашенную лексику, а также умышленно коверкать русский язык.
(+)
Как программист почтенного возраста и стажа со свободным английским (;)) заявляю, что и "винды" и "винда" существовали, но сейчас "винда" совершенно вытеснила множественное.

Answer (score 0):

Марк, я не очень понял: где именно вы советуете поставить запятую - после слова "система"? Если да, там запятая не нужна. Что касается строчной или прописной и кавычек, то конечно, здесь нужна прописная буква и кавычки, т.к. здесь название системы. Строгих рекомендаций о том, какие буквы использовать - латинские или русские - нет. Все зависит от стиля.

Answer (score 0):

Если передавать русскими буквами, то ***"Виндуз"***. Это ближе всего к фактически сложившемуся русскому произношению.
Касательно английского написания. Я бы тоже оставил написание латиницей.
Но такой подход последнее время встречает все возрастающую критику. Иногда разумную, часто - совершенно абсурдистскую, но с языковедами от Госдумы не особо-то и поспоришь.